# JavaScript Inserting HTML Snippet From A Folder

Tags: javascript, html, css, blogs

I want to do something like inserting a 500 character snippet from blog posts that I have. Basically I have a folder that contains the blog posts themselves and a page that contains a bunch of snippets with links to each page. Kind of like WordPress.

Basically what I want to do in JavaScript is have a code that will get a 500 word snippet from a specific CSS class in each page in the blog folder.

I made a custom CSS class called blog-post. All I have right now is this:

```
var word_count = 500,
file = "General Computer Advice Blog Posts",
post = "blog-post",
cutoff = "...",
title_class = "title",
title,
posts[],
blog_post,
display_page = "page.aspx";

$(function () {
    // pseudo Code:
    foreach(var post in posts){
        title = post.get(title_class);//Get the title of the blog post
        blog_post = post.substring(0,word_count) + cutoff;//Get the first 500 characters and append ... to the end of it
        display_page.add(title);//Add the title of the post to the page
        display_page.add(blog_post);//Add the post snippet to the page
    }
});
```

Comment: If you want to read files from your local storage you will need to use the File API. These tutes may help: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/ or https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications

Comment: Javascript doesn't have a `foreach` keyword. You might be looking for [array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: @Nick he said it was pseudo-code.